# How to find coordinates of centre and radius given equation x-2x+y^+10y=-14 x

Tags: analytic-geometry

How do I determine the coordinates of the centre and length of the radius of a circle given the equation x-2x+y^+10y=-14 I don't know how to solve this But I think -14 is one of the coordinates of the radius
This is analytical geometry

Comment: Is the equation $x^2-2x+y^2+10y=-14$. Do you know how "to complete the square" ?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to display Math.  There has to be a typo in the problem.  `x - 2x + y^ + 10y = -14x` is nonsense.  Please proofread/edit your posting.  Your posting has other defects, such as that you haven't shown work.  However, that is all cart before the horse.  Priority needs to be given to editing your question so that it is coherent.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.